# Using graphX in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-graphx

Is there Python API for GraphX? I have come across Scala API but I want to know if its possible to use GraphX functionalities in PySpark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no GraphX API for Python, and there won't be one. See [SPARK-3789 *Python bindings for GraphX*](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3789). GraphX  as such is in the maintenance mode and is no longer actively developed.

You can use [Graphframes](https://github.com/graphframes/graphframes), which provide Dataframe based graph processing, and optionally interface selected GraphX functions under the covers.

Comment: I need some tool to handle large scale social networks can you tell me what can be helpful if not GraphX.

Comment: What about just visualizing a Graphframe?